# Two scrollbars in popup window

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

I've got an issue with the popup windows that display when I click on the book cover images(from a widget) in my sidebar: there are two vertical scrollbars instead of one. Any idea why this is happening and how I may get rid of one of the scrollbars?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Two scrollbars]

Here's my site: [WordPress Blog](http://jchenportfolio.com/blog/)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your site, the double scrollbars are caused by two things:

1. The iframe
2. The CSS declarations applied to a `<div>`

Your iframe has the `scrolling="auto"` property set.  Change this to `scrolling="no"` to turn off the scroll bar.

Also, your containing lightbox div (`<div id="LT_LB">`) has its overflow property set to "auto."  Set this to "hidden" to remove the scroll bar.

Comment: Ack! I think this is going to be beyond me. The pop ups are from a text widget with the following code: <div id="wb4e442f139e10a7c3e619139c29f8b45"></div><script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://www.librarything.com/widget_get.php?userid=jchen147&theID=wb4e442f139e10a7c3e619139c29f8b45" ></script><noscript><a href="http://www.librarything.com/profile/jchen147">My Library</a> at <a href="http://www.librarything.com">LibraryThing</a></noscript>

There doesn't seem to be a way for me to edit the scrolling for the iframe on my end since the original widget is from a third party.

Comment: In that case, I recommend you contact the third party (possibly LibraryThing?) directly and ask them for support ...

Comment: Another comment: I don't have this double scrollbar issue with the Librarything pop up on another WordPress blog I made for a class project using a different theme. So I think this is also theme-related.

Comment: The one thing I see that could be theme related is the `LT_LB` div.  As I say above, you've got overflow set to auto.  If you set overflow to "hidden," one of the scrollbars disappears.